# How to read a JSON file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to read a json file in python but unable to do it. My json file is 436mb in size and I am using python 3.3.4 version
Tried different ways

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('drug-event-0002-of-0002.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
print(data)

Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/533335/Desktop/jsonReadTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1339, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
MemoryError

---------------------------------------------------------------------   
import ijson
with open('drug-event-0002-of-0002.json', 'r') as f:
    parser = ijson.parse(f)
    for prefix, event, value in parser:
        if prefix == "name":
            print(value)

Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/533335/Desktop/jsonReadTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ijson
ImportError: No module named 'ijson'
```

Comment: It seems like your first try worked, it just can't print it. Try printing while iterating over the dictionary.

Comment: [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) certainly looks like it might fit the bill. Have you installed it (it's not part of the standard library)?

Comment: SiHa : I am a beginner in python. So if you guide me on how to install ijson to python, it would be great. Even previously i have been trying installing other packages like NLTK but could not do it.

Comment: @Dean: I tried this now  
import json
f = open('drug-event-0002-of-0002.json', 'r')
json.load(f)
print(f)
f.close() 

and got one line output

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='drug-event-0002-of-0002.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

And how to iterate the first code over the dictionary?

Comment: Try this: 
    `with open('drug-event-0002-of-0002.json') as data_file:`
        `data = json.load(data_file)`
    `for key,value in data.items():`
        `print(key,value)`

Comment: tried it :

results Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/533335/Desktop/jsonReadTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(key,value)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1339, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
MemoryError

Got results    and then error